# Teamcity - Global VCS Root for all projects

Tags: git, version-control, teamcity

I am in-charge of ~40 TeamCity builds across 7 or so projects.  Currently, they each have their own Git credentials, which is silly, because they are actually all using the same logon.  They are only slightly different from each other, in that

- they checkout different branches
- they use a different base repos (but are on the same server)

How can I set this up so they all use the same Git logon in team city, such that when this logon expires, I don't have to reset 30-ish passwords?

I understand that there are build parameters, and I can kind of share VCS roots, but these roots only appear to be visible to builds of the same project... and I don't see a way to do this to the "Root" project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Shared VCS Root**

The Root project would be the place to setup a VCS root that is inherited across all projects; and as the same login is used to authenticate with the host repository server you can simply define this at that root level too.

To add a VCS root in the Root project, navigate to:

`https://{HostServer}/admin/editProject.html?projectId=_Root&tab=projectVcsRoots`

and from there you can click `Create VCS root`.  Any build configuration in your TeamCity instance will then have access to attach that VCS root.  Set the login details when creating that VCS root.

**Parameterising the VCS root**

> they checkout different branches

You can parameterise the `Default branch` to enable the VCS root branch to be dynamically configured based on a build parameter, which would need to be provided / overridden at either a sub-project or configuration level.  For example:

`%system.DefaultBranch%`

as a `Default branch` value would require any configuration using the VCS root to provide a value for `%system.DefaultBranch%`.  You can specify a default value for this parameter at the `Root project` level to make things easier if you have a lot of configurations using, say, `refs/heads/master`.

> they use a different base repos (but are on the same server)

Similarly, you can parameterise the `Fetch URL` to enable the VCS root to be dynamically configured based on a build parameter, which would need to be provided / overridden at either a sub-project or configuration level.  For example:

`git@bitbucket.org:myname/%system.GitRepositoryName%`

as a `Fetch URL` would require any configuration using the VCS root to provide a value for `%system.GitRepositoryName%`.  This can be provided as a Project parameter or a Build Configuration parameter.  If you have multiple build configurations that all use the same repository **under the same project**, then it's probably best to go with the Project parameter approach.

Comment: I'll try this in the morning, but some of this seems to suggest that I'm not as much of admin as I thought I was.

Comment: Ah yes, being able to do this does require System Administrator rights